# Bash shell (Ubuntu) on the command prompt (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to access the ssh server on a Asus with Windows 8 OS from my MBP 2012 with Ubuntu distribution. Is it possible to install the bash shell on Windows 8? I ask this question, because I'd like to use the same commands I use normally with Ubuntu, but on Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The feature is Windows 10-only. From [the installation guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide):

> #### Prerequisites
>
> 1. Your PC must be running a 64-bit version of **Windows 10 Anniversary Update build 14393 or later**

Instead, you can use Cygwin, Msys2, etc.

Comment: It seems that Cygwin works well

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity yes, but that's a topic for [su].